# Json schema - is it an object or is it an array?

Tags: c#, jsonschema

I'm writing the json schema for my config file. I want to specify the config schema for Generators, a loosely coupled component of my program. I, owner of the containing project, own 2 of these, but in future there will likely be others, and users can add their own at runtime by registering helper assemblies. A generator must have a name, but will then have it's own specific options.

Because loosely coupled and unknown number, I think I should represent these as an array of objects, each with a "name" property...

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../../../queryfirst.sharedall/qfconfig.schema.json#",
  ...
  "generators": [
    {
      "name": "cSharp",
      "generateAsync": true
    },
    {
      "name": "tsInterfaceFromDto",
      "outputDir": "clientApp/interfaces"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I (how do I?) conditionally specify a generator's properties in my json schema...

```
if name = cSharp 
    properties = [
        generateAsync
        ...
    ]
if name = tsInterfaceFromDto
    properties = [
        outputDir
        ...
    ]
```

For bonus points, how can people contributing future Generators extend my config schema to inject the config for their generators?

Comment: I guess -- just a rough idea, really -- for each of your generator objects (cSharp/tsInterfaceFromDto), you chould define schemas where each uses a regex pattern on the "name" property constraining its value to the respective object name. Then you could combine these schemas using the "oneOf" schema composition, and use the composed oneOf schema as items schema for the generators array. What i currently don't know is how you could specify a schema that disallows placing multiple objects with the same name into the generators array :-(

Comment: "_how can people contributing future Generators extend my config schema_" Well, i guess it all depends on what level of Json Schema proficiency you demand/request from them. If you expect them to not have a very competent understanding of Json schemas, or worry about them messing up the overall schema, perhaps write a little utility where they can input/edit the pertinent generator config data and the utility then modifies the schema file.